# Can somebody explain and solve my Value Error when reading in from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason my code(following) has brought up a Value Error which I cannot understand. Please evaluate my code too. You can find the project I am trying to do at 
http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/226767-unit-j276-03-programming-project-task-1-sample-non-exam-assessment.pdf

```
fileid = "details for nea.txt"
ID = []
surname = []
forename = []
dob = []
addr = []
addrT = []
addrTh = []
addrF = []
addrFi = []
homNum = []
gend = []
tutor = []
schoolEm = []

def Read():
    file = open(fileid, "r")
    Record = file.readline()
    for line in Record:
        line = line.strip()
        A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M = line.split(',')
        ID.append(A)
        surname.append(B)
        forename.append(C)
        dob.append(D)
        addr.append(E)
        addrT.append(F)
        addrTh.append(G)
        addrF.append(H)
        addrFi.append(I)
        homNum.append(J)
        gend.append(K)
        tutor.append(L)
        schoolEm.append(M)   
    file.close()

def Save():
    Record = []
    file = open(fileid,"w")
    for i in range(len(ID)):
        Record.append(ID[i] +","+surname[i]+","+forename[i]+","+dob[i]+","+addr[i]+","+addrT[i]+","+addrTh[i]+","+addrF[i]+","+addrFi[i]+","+homNum[i]+","+gend[i]+","+tutor[i]+","+schoolEm[i]+"\n")
    file.writelines(Record)
    file.close()
Read()
print(ID)
print(surname)
```

The Text File I used goes as following:

```
  01,abe,fat,01/02/02,5,Stoney Lane,Stur,Dorset,DR101LM,0123,M,C,email@sc. The lists titled addr, addrT represent the different lines of address.
```

Comment: Please post the error stack as well.

Comment: Ok I will give me a minute

Comment: Try changing `file.readline()` to `file.readlines()`.

Comment: @srig: More like: Use the `csv` module correctly in the first place.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Sebjv\Desktop\NEA Trial school.py", line 44, in <module>
            Read()
          File "C:\Users\Sebjv\Desktop\NEA Trial school.py", line 21, in Read
            A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M = line.split(',')
        ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 13, got 1)

Comment: This an alternative method to csv if you are not going to contribute don't post Shadow Ranger

Comment: I did initially use file.readlines() but the same error came up so because the text file was only one line long I tried to change it

Comment: `file.readlines()` is correct here, if you are still getting the same error it is because there are not enough values on at least one line of the file. That said - perhaps looking at the `csv` module wouldn't be a bad idea, as it handles a lot of corner-cases that you currently are not (and realistically cannot be expected to do yourself). *[Side note: Mr Leeman's requirement number 6 is idiotic and whoever thought the developer should decide which reports he will need should take a refresher in setting client expectations and determining client requirements]*

Comment: Hint: print `Record` before you enter that `for` loop. And if you change to `file.readlines()` consider what happens if the data contains any empty lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bilkokuya but I have seen the example I am trying to accomplish work and I would like to get it to work myself as an alternate method to csv. The error still occurs and you can see from the text file that there is enough characters (and there certainly isn't one). I also agree that requirement 6 is stupid.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring that helped a lot. I had no idea the text file contained empty lines!

Comment: PM 2Ring can you set the comment as an answer so that I can end the question.

Comment: One thing I'd suggest for future, is to expect the text file may be broken somewhere and ensure you are ready to handle the errors that do come up elegantly (for example, checking for empty lines and then printing a warning that "your datafile appears to have an error on line <x>" or similar, then skipping to the next "good" line).

Comment: I will bear that in mind. Can you also put that as an answer so that I can close the question! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put last three lines inside `main`. Value error should go away